# Android Navigation Drawer - More than one View

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

So I'm using Navigation drawer, and mainly I'm simply clearing the view of elements and then adding them back in for dynamic content. One screen will be mainly non-dynamic content, unlike the rest of them, so I'd like to create two xml layouts, one for the dynamic content and one for the static.

Problem is, the Navigation Drawer isn't showing up when I switch to the new view.

Here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("area", "Home");
    editor.commit();
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
    setupDrawer(0);

}

private void itemSelected(String selection, int position){

        DataClass dc = new DataClass(this);
        dc.setSection(selection, this);

        ArrayList<String> menuArray = dc.getMenuArray(selection);
        String[] menuList = menuArray.toArray(new String[menuArray.size()]); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupDrawer(1);
        standardDisplay(selection, menuList, 1);    
}

private void setupDrawer(int i){
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mForumTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu_array);
    if (i == 0){
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer_layout);
    }else if(i == 1){
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mForumTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
  }

private void standardDisplay(String section, String[] menuList, int position){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(section);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, menuList));
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    setMainView(section, menuList[position]);
}

private void setMainView(String section, String selection){
    mTableView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scroll_layout);
    mTableView.removeAllViews();
    DataClass dc = new DataClass(this);

    ArrayList<String> info = dc.getInfoArray(section, selection);
    String[] instructions = info.get(0).split("\\|"); 
    String[] values = info.get(1).split("\\|");
    for(int i=0; i < instructions.length; i++){
            if (instructions[i].equals("@image")){
                ImageView newImage = new ImageView(this);

                newImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                 mTableView.addView(newImage);
            }else{

                TextView newText = new TextView(this);
                newText.setText(instructions[i] + ": " + values[i]);
                newText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                newText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
                //newRow.addView(newText);
                 mTableView.addView(newText);
            }

    }

    TextView newText = new TextView(this);

    newText.setText(info.get(2));
    newText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
    newText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

     mTableView.setPadding(60, 20, 60, 0);
     mTableView.addView(newText);
}
```

main_screen.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
    android:id="@+id/MainText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:text="@string/Dashboard"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

</FrameLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
 </FrameLayout>
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of having two drawer layouts, why don't you use the same drawer but implement two separate adapters?

Comment: Likely due to the fact this is only my second android application and my first one was over two years ago.  I'm not sure how to use two separate adapters. :-/

Comment: You could keep two global references to your adapters (when you use new ArrayAdapter<String>(...) assign these instances to global variables), and use ListView.setAdapter(adapter_to_display) to switch between adapters.  Also, looking at the docs might help:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: I guess I'll start a new project and figure our array adapters then. If I can get it working I'll come back and up vote your comments.